# How can I swipe between view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, swipe

I want to add a swipe action to my app. Basically I have 5 view controllers and I main view controller. On my main view controller I have a view and I am calling the content from other 5 view controllers to that view. And I want to swipe those 5 view controllers.

My code:

```
import UIKit

class TabViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!
    @IBOutlet var backgroundView: UIImageView!


    var movingView = UIView()

    var rifleViewController: UIViewController!
    var pistolViewController: UIViewController!
    var shotgunViewController: UIViewController!
    var smgsViewController: UIViewController!
    var sniperViewController: UIViewController!

    var viewControllers: [UIViewController]!
    var selectedIndex: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        rifleViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "rifles")
        sniperViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "snipers")
        smgsViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "smgss")
        shotgunViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "shotguns")
        pistolViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pistols")
        viewControllers = [rifleViewController,
                           pistolViewController,
                           shotgunViewController,
                           smgsViewController,
                           sniperViewController]

        buttons[selectedIndex].isSelected = true
        didPressTab(buttons[selectedIndex])

        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        movingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 80, width: screenWidth / 5, height: 5))
        movingView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        backgroundView.addSubview(movingView)


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func didPressTab(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let previousIndex = selectedIndex

        selectedIndex = sender.tag

        buttons[previousIndex].isSelected = false
        let previousVC = viewControllers[previousIndex]

        previousVC.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
        previousVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
        previousVC.removeFromParentViewController()

        sender.isSelected = true

        let vc = viewControllers[selectedIndex]

        addChildViewController(vc)

        vc.view.frame = contentView.bounds
        contentView.addSubview(vc.view)
        vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        let newx = sender.frame.origin.x

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            self.movingView.frame.origin.x = newx
        }


        }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You must go for [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipageviewcontroller).

With the [setViewControllers(_:direction:animated:completion:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipageviewcontroller/1614087-setviewcontrollers) you can set an array of your view controllers and also you can customise the animation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am a beginner, can you please tell me how should i do this inside my code.

Comment: @VolkanElçi Here are some links got through it https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/12/23/swift-uipageviewcontroller-tutorial/ 
http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/easy-steps-to-implement-uipageviewcontroller-in-swift

Answer (score 1):

Add on all of your viewController two `Swipe Gesture Recognizer`. Take care that you really drag and drop them onto the `View Controller`in the hierarchy because else it might not work (For the most left and most right view controller you just have to add one `swipe gesture recognizer`). After that change for one of the the `Swipe Gesture Recognizer`per view controller the `Swipe` option in the attribute inspector from the standard `Left` to `Right`. 
Create from each view controller to the next a `Show`seague and one back. Give them an `Identifier` you can remember. Then write something like that into each `ViewController.swift` and link the `@IBAction` with the two `Swipe Gesture Recognizer` of each corresponding view controller:

```
 @IBAction func didSwipe(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
      if sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left {
          performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifierOfSegue", sender: nil)
      }

      if sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right {
          performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifierOfOtheSegue", sender: nil)
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question, but you can add (from Interface Builder) a UIGestureRecognizer (for the swipe action) to the View and in the selector of that gesture, you present the View you'd like to show.